# Reducing noise in AC clamp meter

Tags: power-electronics

[image]

I am currently using one of these AC clamp meters to read an 25Hz square wave signal along a wire attached to a wall. Unfortunately, there seems to be a lot of noise of other frequencies around this wire. I want to somehow attach a low pass filter to this AC clamp. Is that possible?

Comment: A true square wave has lots and lots of harmonics at different frequencies due to the fast rising  and falling edges... This may not be suitable for measuring square waves as most are intended for sine waves. Filtering the signal with a choke may help as it will smooth the wave form, but that may ruin the usefulness of the signal..? So.. why a 25Hz square wave ?

Comment: @spoon the cable was designed that way, I can't change it unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the impact of high frequencies simply place a capacitor between the positive and negative terminal of the AC clamp.